# Discord bot stops playing music after the first song [python]

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

My bot plays the first song, then stops reacting to other commands to play songs.

Here's my code:

```
    @wb.command(pass_context=True)
    async def play(ctx, url):
        author = ctx.message.author
        channel = author.voice_channel
        vc = await wb.join_voice_channel(channel)
        player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
        player.start()

    @wb.command(pass_context=True)
    async def leavevoice(ctx):
        for x in wb.voice_clients:
        if(x.server == ctx.message.server):
        return await x.disconnect()
```

I get no error code, it just doesn't react to my commands.

Comment: Is that how `leavevoice` appears in your source?  There are indentation errors.  What errors appear in the terminal from which you're running your bot?

Comment: I have no errors, if there are indentation errors, i just wrote that wrong.
First song plays normally, but the second song doesnt want to play when i use the same command.